# OpenPyXL traverses rows until find an empty row

Tags: python, openpyxl

There is a `a.xlsx` file, 92427 lines (no including the header). I open `a.xlsx`, manually delete many rows (remain the first 27 rows) and save as `a_sample.xlsx` as a sample input.

I read data from `a_sample.xlsx` with the following code.

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(file_workbook, read_only=True)
ws = wb.sheetnames[0]  # wb.get_sheet_by_name(wb.get_sheet_names()[0])

for idx, row in enumerate(ws.iter_rows(row_offset=1)): # row_offset=1, skip the header
    print(idx)
```

The last line of output is `92426`, not `26`. What are possible reasons?

I make OpenPyXL traverse rows ending at an empty row with:

```py
for idx, row in enumerate(ws.iter_rows(row_offset=1)): 
    if row[0].value is None:
        break
```

Comment: ***`enumerate(ws.iter_rows(row_offset=1))`***: There is no [`row_offset=`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.html#Worksheet.iter_rows) named parameter, show the Traceback. Furthermore `enumerate(` should start with `1` to be in sync. This: `row[0]`, will **only** compare the first Column's Cell, is this intentional?

Comment: `ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name(wb.get_sheet_names()[0])` is the old syntax. New style is `ws = wb[wb.sheetnames[0]]`

Comment: What does `ws.max_column` state?

Comment: @Joe thx for pointing out this. The new style is more concise.

Comment: I suspect the check `value is None` isn't sufficient. It won't, for example, catch cells with empty strings.

Comment: @SparkAndShine This is a known issue: [delete_rows-does-not-work-on-deleting](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/964/delete_rows-does-not-work-on-deleting), [cell-max_row-reports-higher-than-actual](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/514/cell-max_row-reports-higher-than-actual)

Answer (score 0):

There are probably non-empty cells somewhere. Please look at `ws.max_row` and `ws.max_column`, then check the cell `[ws.max_row, ws.max_column]` manually in the file.

As already mentioned, there is no keyword `row_offset`, but you can use something like

```
for idx, row in enumerate(ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_col=3, max_row=20)):
```

where `max_row <= ws.max_column`.

Comment: `row_offset` is deprecated several versions ago. My version is `openpyxl==2.4.0`. `row_offset` works for me.